# I'm trying some questions out before my finals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, mysqli

This is the diagram [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUNEM.png)

I can't seem to figure out how to do these questions. i'm not good at joins can someone please help me
Store Suppliers
Produce a query to display the stores and the suppliers which supply products to those stores.  Show the names of the store and the managers of the store, the supplier name, contact name and phone number of the supplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

Query 8 – Sorry, didn't really understand it.

Query 9 – 
`SELECT ShiftID, EndTime - StartTime AS Downtime, T2.*
    FROM SHIFT T1 JOIN STAFF T2 ON T1.StaffID = T2.StaffID
    WHERE EndTime - StartTime >= 28
ORDER BY EndTime - StartTime DESC;`

Query 10 – 
`SELECT T1.*, Type, FibreContent, CarboContent, NULL AS FatContent, NULL AS ProteinContent FROM PRODUCT T1 JOIN VEGETARIAN T2 ON T1.ProductID = T2.ProductID
    UNION
SELECT T1.*, Type, NULL FibreContent, NULL CarboContent, FatContent, ProteinContent FROM PRODUCT T1 JOIN HEALTHY T2 ON T1.ProductID = T2.ProductID
    ORDER BY Type;`

Comment: I'm getting an error for the 10th query
Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.